Error Base de Datos - Crystal Report Visual Studio 2022
Estoy intentando actualizar unos reportes de CrystalReport elaborados aproximadamente en el año 2002 los cuales son "llamados" desde una aplicación desarrollada en VB6. Por lo que se busca migrar todo esto a tecnologías más modernas, entonces se decidió implementar los cambios con Visual Studio 2022 C# MVC
Contexto de la estructura de los reportes:
reportMain.rpt --> Está conectado a unaBD SYBASE ASE16 mediante ODBC 64-bits; su DataSource es un StoredProcedure.
Este reporte contiene 4 SubReportes:
report1.rpt, report2.rpt, report3.rpt, report4.rpt
cada uno de estos reportes también tienen un DataSource obtenido desde un StoredProcedure. Pero, a pesar de tener su DataSource "propio", cada subreporte está linkeado al reporte original en base a sus parámetros de entrada, tal como se indica en la siguiente imagen:

OficNumOfic y numero51 son los parámetros de entrada del reportMain.rpt que a su vez son los parámetros de entrada del StoredProcedure utilizado como DataSource.
Cuando estoy en el visualizador del reporte en Visual Studio, al realizar la prueba de conexión con mi BD, esta funciona sin problemas e incluso en la vista previa del reporte me extrae todos los datos, por lo que doy por sentado que la conexión se está realizando bien.
Ahora el contexto de la ejecución del código:
Desde un formulario web se ejecuta el siguiente POST:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReporteBonificacion(long Registro)
    {
        var cuenta = (Account)Session["Cuenta"];
        var random = new Random();
        long numRnd = random.Next(10000); // Genera un número aleatorio para el reporte

        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Models/CrystalReports/reportMain.rpt");
        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);

        // Asigna parámetros al reporte principal
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@OficNumOfic", Registro);
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@numero51", numRnd);
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Usuario", cuenta.usuario);
        //subRpt 1
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@OficNumOfic", Registro, "report1.rpt");
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@numero51", numRnd, "report1.rpt");
        //subRpt 2
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@OficNumOfic", Registro, "report2.rpt");
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@numero", numRnd, "report2.rpt");
        //subRpt 3
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@OficNumOfic", Registro, "report3.rpt");
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@numero51", numRnd, "report3.rpt");
        //subRpt 4
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@OficNumOfic", Registro, "report4.rpt");
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@numero", numRnd, "report4.rpt");


        // Accede a la colección de parámetros del reporte
        ParameterFields parameterFields = reportDocument.ParameterFields;

        // Itera sobre los parámetros e imprime sus nombres y valores
        foreach (ParameterField parameter in parameterFields)
        {
            string parameterInfo = $"{parameter.Name}: ";

            foreach (ParameterValue value in parameter.CurrentValues)
            {
                if (value is ParameterDiscreteValue discreteValue)
                {
                    parameterInfo += discreteValue.Value.ToString() + ", ";
                }
                else if (value is ParameterRangeValue rangeValue)
                {
                    parameterInfo += $"Rango de {rangeValue.StartValue} a {rangeValue.EndValue}, ";
                }
            }

            // Imprime la información del parámetro, quitando la última coma y espacio si es necesario
            Debug.WriteLine(parameterInfo.TrimEnd(',', ' '));
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"{reportDocument.Name}: {reportDocument.DataSourceConnections[0].ServerName}");
        foreach (ReportDocument subReport in reportDocument.Subreports)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{subReport.Name}: {subReport.DataSourceConnections[0].ServerName}");
        }


        Stream reportStream = reportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        reportDocument.Close();
        reportDocument.Dispose();

        return File(reportStream, "application/pdf", "NombreReporte.pdf");
    }

Adjunto la salida de los Print de cada ParameterField:
@OficNumOfic: 662679
@numero51: 4929
@Usuario: F_vluna
@OficNumOfic: 662679
@numero51: 4929
@OficNumOfic: 662679
@numero: 4929
@OficNumOfic: 662679
@numero51: 4929
@OficNumOfic: 662679
@numero: 4929

En el código se realizan unos Print de consola para revisar los valores que se están asignando a cada propiedad. Lo cual también he observado que se realiza sin ningún problema (todas las propiedades obtienen su valor correspondiente). Entonces al momento que la aplicación ejecuta la siguiente instrucción;
Stream reportStream = reportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

obtengo el siguiente error:
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: 'No se pudo conectar con la base de datos.'

He realizado cambios de usuarios en la conexión ODBC, cambios en el reporte y siempre llego al mismo error señalado anteriormente.
Comprendo que el nombre de las variables son recursivas e incluso pueden estar mal empleadas, pero como mencioné al inicio de la pregunta, estos reportes fueron desarrollados en aproximadamente en 2002 jaja.
Si alguien con mayor conocimiento en Crystal Report u ODBC me pudiera explicar por que al probar la conexión del ODBC y el Cristal Report Preview se conectan sin problemas, funcionando todo con normalidad. Y al momento de ejecutar el código en el POST este levanta un error de LogOn
De antemano, agradezco sus respuestas.
PS - Editada
De un chispazo se me ocurrió imprimir las propiedades de conexión del reporte:
    private void PrintConnectionDetails(ReportDocument report, string reportName)
{
    foreach (Table table in report.Database.Tables)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Report: {reportName}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"DataSource: {table.Name}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"ServerName: {table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"DatabaseName: {table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"UserID: {table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Type: {table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Password: {table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password}");
        Debug.WriteLine("===============================================================");
    }
}

y en la salida obtengo algo así:
    ===============================================================
Report: report4.rpt
DataSource: BNInfBonDet;1
ServerName: MENELAO64
DatabaseName: 
UserID: sa
Type: CRQE
Password: 
===============================================================

ahí me di cuenta que DataBaseName y Password no se estaban considerando. Entonces ingresé en bruto esos datos con el siguiente código:
        private void ConfigureDatabaseName(ReportDocument reportDocument, string databaseName, string Pass)
    {
        foreach (Table table in reportDocument.Database.Tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = Pass;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
        }
    }


        ConfigureDatabaseName(reportDocument, "bdName", "userPass");

y ahí se exportó el reporte, pero mi duda es... ¿Por qué pasa esto?, ¿Por que, a pesar de especificar en el ODBC el nombre de la bd, al cargar el reporte no aparece seteada?
